# Trying to update phalcon to 3.0 on Debian 8 v-server

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian, phalcon

First of all: I only know some basics on linux, but I wanted to try out Phalcon. So I've rented a small v-server with Debian 8 and installed php7.
At the time phalcon was at version 2.1.0r and I followed the tutorials until it seemed to work. Then I've had no time to really start working on it anymore (just created the first to 2 controllers from the tutorial).
Now I do have an idea for a test project and a little time, but I've seen that Phalcon 3.0 is out.

So I went into my cphalcon folder and got the 3.0 branch via git.
With `git status` I get `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/3.0.x'.`

Then I switched to the "build" folder and ran `sudo ./install`.
The process ran through without any errors and both `/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/phalcon/php_phalcon.h` and `/usr/lib/php/20151012/phalcon.so` are shown as recently updated within their respective folders.

In `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d` I do have a link called `30-phalcon.ini` that points to `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phalcon.ini` containing only the line `extension=phalcon.so`

Then I've restarted the server via `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`.
When I run phpinfo(), it does still show phalcon version `2.1.0r` though.

I'll try to get a linux training, but I'd love to try starting on Phalcon until then

---

**The solution:**
First, I recompiled via zephir, then I restarted php.

```
$ cd cphalcon/
$ zephir fullclean
$ zephir compile
$ cd build/
$ sudo ./install
$ /etc/init.d/nginx restart
$ /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart
```

I don't know if I needed to do all this, but it worked and I'm happy. Thank you all.

Comment: run the command `sudo service php7-fpm restart` to restart your PHP service. Then the updated phalcon version should be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dev branches, e.g `3.0.x` always use [Zephir](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir):

```
# PHP 5
$ zephir fullclean
$ zephir build

# PHP 7
$ zephir fullclean
$ zephir build --backend=ZendEngine3
```

Comment: `zephir build --backend=ZendEngine3` zephir already detects backend, this is only needed as far as i know if we want to generate php7 extension code while being on php5. At least i both on php5 and php7 using just zephir build

Answer (score 1):

`Service php7-fpm restart` ? Nginx is not php handler, it's fpm which handles php.